# How to add a div every 3rd map/loop inside map react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a div every 3rd loop when mapping through my profile objects. This is so I can show 3 items at a time in the carousel setting of my little app. However I am getting syntax errors, can anybody help?!

[image]

```
// Renders the selected profile
let renderProfilesCarousel = selectedProfile.map(profile => {

  return(

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedProfile.length; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 2) {
        <div className="sliderContainer">
      }
    }

    <a href={profile.postUrl} target="_blank" data-interception="off" key={shortid.generate()}> 
      <div> 
        <DocumentCard
          aria-label={profile.postContent}
          className={styles.linkedInDocCard}
        > 
          { profile.imgUrl && 
            <Image
              src={profile.imgUrl}
              imageFit={ImageFit.cover}
              height={168}
            />
          }
        </DocumentCard>
      </div>
    </a>

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedProfile.length; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 2) {
        </div>
      }
    }

  )
});
```

Comment: In react, any js code needs to be wrapped in braces `{}` in jsx.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem. Do you need to wrap every 3 elements around a div?

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to this:

```
{
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedProfile.length; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 2) {
        <div className="sliderContainer"></div>
      }
    }
}
```

In react , whenever you want to use javascript, you start with curly brackets `{}`.
You also didnt close your div inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the function signature for map:

```js
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Returned value for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

So the second parameter of the callbackfunction is the index of the current item in the array. So u can just:

```js
let renderProfilesCarousel = selectedProfile.map((profile, index) => {
  return (
    {
      if(index % 3 === 0 ){
        <div className="sliderContainer">
      }
    }
    //... content to be wrapped
    {
      if(index % 3 === 2 ){
        </div>
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work with the latest version of React.

Answer (score 0):

You can either put it in the render or make a function that you call that returns something.

function example:

```
returnJSXHere = () => {
   for (var i = 0; i < selectedProfile.length; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 2) {
        return <div className="sliderContainer"></div>
      }
    }
};
```

usage example:

```
{this.returnJSXHere()}
```